# SIP по GPON от МГТС

Tags: пароль, asterisk, sip, телефония

Коллеги! Недавно стал "пользователем" GPON от МГТС. Сразу заинтересовал вопрос, как переключить SIP из ONT в свой Asterisk. Монтажники поставили мне Huawei HG8245H - ни как не могу вынуть из него пароль для сипа. Помню, кода стоял ZTE F660, там пароль можно было без проблем получить из шела. В хуавее в файле конфига, пароль находится в зашифрованном виде.
Вчера получилось слить образ системного раздела со всеми конфигами с роутера. Но поиски кодировщика паролей успехом не увенчались.
Может, кто уже сталкивался с подобным вопросом и способен просветить?
Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Хочу заметить что даже если получится достать заветный пароль, все равно нет гарантий что оно проработает достаточно долго, т.к. провайдер периодически зырит логи и банит неверных. Т.е. для Вас, как пользователя, это чревато лишь тем что придется сходить в офис и поменять модем.

Comment: Будет отличный повод сменить модель модема ;)